# chart currency are not rebuilding after using setState()

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, charts, setstate

I am building an application that shows live chart price of a cryptocurrencies that also have a fiat currency exchange between 'USD', 'GBP' and 'EUR'.

here is my code of subscribing to a websocket to plot the cryptocurrencies price on the chart. (i'm using cryptocompare api).

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:syncfusion_flutter_charts/charts.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:web_socket_channel/io.dart';

const String apiKey =
    "***";

class Chart extends StatefulWidget {
  final String cryptocurrencyName;
  final String currency;

  const Chart(
      {Key? key, required this.cryptocurrencyName, required this.currency})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChartState createState() => _ChartState();
}

class _ChartState extends State<Chart> {
  late final IOWebSocketChannel channel;
  List<DataPoint> chartData = [];
  bool isSubscribed = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    channel = IOWebSocketChannel.connect(
      'wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/v2?api_key=$apiKey',
    );
    subscribeToStream();
  }

  void toggleSubscription() {
    if (isSubscribed) {
      unsubscribeToStream();
    } else {
      subscribeToStream();
    }
  }

  void subscribeToStream() {
    final subRequest = {
      "action": "SubAdd",
      "subs": ["2~Coinbase~${widget.cryptocurrencyName}~${widget.currency}"]
    };
    final subRequestJson = jsonEncode(subRequest);
    channel.sink.add(subRequestJson);
    isSubscribed = true;
  }

  void unsubscribeToStream() {
    final subRequest = {
      "action": "SubRemove",
      "subs": ["2~Coinbase~${widget.cryptocurrencyName}~${widget.currency}"]
    };
    final subRequestJson = jsonEncode(subRequest);
    channel.sink.add(subRequestJson);
    isSubscribed = false;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    channel.sink.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void updateChartData(num price, int lastUpdate) {
    if (chartData.length >= 20) {
      chartData.removeAt(0);
    }
    DateTime dateTime = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(lastUpdate * 1000);
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('HH:mm:ss').format(dateTime);
    chartData.add(DataPoint(formattedDate, price.toDouble()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
        elevation: 4,
        child: Container(
          height: 400,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: channel.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final message = snapshot.data;
                final decodedMessage = jsonDecode(message.toString());
                final messageType = decodedMessage['TYPE'];
                final currency = decodedMessage['TOSYMBOL'];

                if (messageType == '2') {
                  decodedMessage.forEach((key, value) {
                    if (key == 'PRICE') {
                      num price = decodedMessage['PRICE'];
                      int lastUpdate = decodedMessage['LASTUPDATE'];
                      updateChartData(price, lastUpdate);
                    }
                  });
                }
              }

              return SfCartesianChart(
                zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(
                  enablePinching: true,
                  enableDoubleTapZooming: true,
                  enablePanning: true,
                ),
                primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
                  labelPlacement: LabelPlacement.onTicks,
                  labelRotation: 45,
                ),
                primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(
                  anchorRangeToVisiblePoints: false,
                  numberFormat: NumberFormat('#.5'),
                  labelAlignment: LabelAlignment.start,
                ),
                series: <LineSeries<DataPoint, String>>[
                  LineSeries<DataPoint, String>(
                    dataSource: chartData,
                    xValueMapper: (DataPoint data, _) => data.x,
                    yValueMapper: (DataPoint data, _) => data.y,
                    markerSettings: const MarkerSettings(isVisible: true),
                    color: Colors.pinkAccent,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DataPoint {
  final String x;
  final double y;

  DataPoint(this.x, this.y);
}
```

and here is the file code where i call the chart following its cryptocurrencies description

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../chart.dart';

class CryptoCardBody extends StatefulWidget {
  CryptoCardBody({
    Key? key,
    required this.name,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.price,
    required this.change,
    required this.marketCap,
    required this.symbol,
    required this.percent,
    required this.cryptocurrencyName,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final String? name;
  final String? imageUrl;
  final num? price;
  final num? change;
  final String? marketCap;
  final String? symbol;
  final num? percent;
  final String cryptocurrencyName;

  @override
  _CryptoCardBodyState createState() => _CryptoCardBodyState();
}

class _CryptoCardBodyState extends State<CryptoCardBody> {
  List<String> dropdownItems = ['USD', 'GBP', 'EUR'];
  late String selectedCurrency;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    selectedCurrency = 'USD';
  }

  void updateCurrency(String currency) {
    setState(() {
      selectedCurrency = currency;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("Here: $selectedCurrency");
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Column(
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 100,
                    child: Image.network(
                      'https://www.cryptocompare.com${widget.imageUrl}',
                      width: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    widget.name!,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Market Cap: ${widget.marketCap}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Price: ${widget.price}',
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      // color: Color(0xFF979797),
                      fontSize: 18,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    widget.change!.toDouble() < 0
                        ? widget.change!.toDouble().toStringAsFixed(2)
                        : '+${widget.change!.toDouble().toStringAsFixed(2)}',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: widget.change!.toDouble() > 0
                          ? const Color(0xFF57992D)
                          : Colors.red,
                      fontSize: 18,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
            ],
          ),
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                    Radius.circular(20.0),
                  ),
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 1.0,
                  ),
                ),
                child: DropdownButton<String>(
                  items: dropdownItems.map((String value) {
                    return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                      value: value,
                      child: Text(value),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    if (value != null) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedCurrency = value;
                      });
                      updateCurrency(value);
                    }
                  },
                  value: selectedCurrency,
                  hint: const Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Text('option'),
                  ),
                  isExpanded: false,
                  underline: const SizedBox(),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Chart(
            cryptocurrencyName: widget.symbol!,
            currency: selectedCurrency,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the problem that I'm facing right now is that, although the value of the drop down menu are being passed to the `widget.currency` in the class chart, the chart itself doesn't seem to change according to the chosen currencies.

I thought using `setState()` would fix the problem but it doesn't. I've have try a few different thing but it still doesn't solve the problem that I'm facing right now.

I would really appreciated it if you can help me solve this problem. You can ask me any question in the comment.